# Errors in file handling

Tags: c#, file-handling

I'm currently trying to enter data into a text file using Stream Writer and Stream Reader to output the info, in this case - First Name, Surname & Age. Then with the information I am wishing to output this into a table listed as below:

```
First Name          Surname              Age
Etc                 Etc                  Etc
```

however I'm having some problems working it out!!

Please see my code below, can anyone explain why I'm getting the following error messages?

> Error 1   Use of unassigned local variable 'firstname'
>
> Error 2   Use of unassigned local variable 'lastname'
>
> Error 3   Use of unassigned local variable 'age'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO; 

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{// Start namespace
    class Program
    {// Start Class
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {// Start Main
            // Declaration Strings

            String firstname; // Declares Name as a String
            String lastname; // Declares Surname as a String
            String age; // Declares Age as a String
            int Counter; // Declares Counter as an Integer

            FileInfo fleNames = new FileInfo("Names.txt"); // Creates fleNames as an Object, using Names.txt as the file name
            StreamWriter swrNames = fleNames.CreateText(); // Informs fleName to Create Text

            for (Counter = 0; Counter < 1; Counter++)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter Your First Name:"); // Writes users first name using Stream Writer Command
                firstname = Console.ReadLine(); 
                swrNames.WriteLine(firstname); // This dictates where the first name will be stored in the text file
                swrNames.Flush();

                Console.Write("Enter Your Surname"); // Writes users first name using Stream Writer Command
                lastname = Console.ReadLine();
                swrNames.WriteLine(lastname); // This dictates where the last name will be stored in the text file
                swrNames.Flush();


                Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Age"); // Writes users first name using Stream Writer Command
                age = Console.ReadLine();
                swrNames.WriteLine(age); // This dictates where the age will be stored in the text file
                swrNames.Flush();
                Console.Clear();


            }


            swrNames.Close();

            String NamesTable;

            StreamReader swreNames = File.OpenText("Names.txt");

            while ((NamesTable = swreNames.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(NamesTable);

            }

            swreNames.Close();

            Console.ReadLine();

            FileInfo fleNamesTwo = new FileInfo("NamesTwo.txt");

            StreamWriter swrNamesTwo = null;


            // ------------ CHECK APPEND TO A FILE --------------

            if (fleNames.Exists == true)
            {
                swrNames = fleNames.AppendText();
            }
            else // -- Create a new text file 
            { // Declare Strings
                String Name; // Name
                String Surnames; // Surname
                String Ages; // Age
                swrNamesTwo = fleNamesTwo.CreateText();

                Console.Write("Enter Your First Name");
                Name = Console.ReadLine();
                swrNamesTwo.WriteLine(Name);
                swrNamesTwo.Flush();

                Console.Write("Enter Your Surname");
                Surnames = Console.ReadLine();
                swrNamesTwo.WriteLine(Surnames);
                swrNamesTwo.Flush();


                Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Age");
                Ages = Console.ReadLine();
                swrNamesTwo.WriteLine(Ages);
                swrNamesTwo.Flush();
                Console.Clear();


            }

            Console.Clear();


            Console.SetCursorPosition(15, 2);

            Console.Write("--- Names Table ---");

            Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 4);

            Console.Write("First Name");

            Console.SetCursorPosition(28, 4);

            Console.Write("Surname");

            Console.SetCursorPosition(48, 4);

            Console.Write("Age");

            Console.ReadLine();

            do  
            {
                //Read a File a Streamreader Command

                swrNames.WriteLine(firstname); // Reads from first name from file Names.txt
                Console.SetCursorPosition(10, Counter + 6); // Aligns first name within table settings 

                swrNames.WriteLine(lastname); // Reads from last name from file Names.txt
                Console.SetCursorPosition(28, Counter + 6); 

                swrNames.WriteLine(age); // Reads from age from file Names.txt
                Console.SetCursorPosition(48, Counter + 6);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} is {2} years old", firstname, lastname, age);


                Console.Clear();  //Clears Screen
                Console.ReadLine();



            } while ((firstname = swreNames.ReadLine()) != null); //Writes out the input from the text file
        }
    }
}
```

Ok so you helpful people have got me past the errors!! Thank you :)

However, (there's always a however!!!) 
I still cant get the stream writer/reader to display the results in the table. I get the table to appear after the results but the table is blank, with the exception of the table headings all in their neat placeholders! 
ANYONE..... :):):)

Comment: Initialize your variables, to null or String.Empty

Comment: have you thought about `Initializing` the string variables = `string.Empty`
`string firstname = string.Empty; // Declares Name as a String`
`string lastname = string.empty; // Declares Surname as a String`
`string age = string.empty; // De`

Comment: Preferably null, because the compiler/resharper has some understanding of it being an "empty" value.

Comment: `Stream of Conscious Coding` you need to Refactor all that code into using Methods it's a coding mess break your code down into smaller more readable methods

Comment: sorry the loop counter = 0; counter < 1; Counter++) is only there for testing - it should be for 10 spaces but its quicker for me to test it using just one 'name;

Comment: `BaZ H` bad coding practice perhaps you should test your case with as bigger sample never assume that just because it works on one test case that it will work for all..

Comment: thank you for your advice, its all really helpful... its fair to say i'm learning... fast!

Comment: there are no errors now but i still can't display the names entered into the table. everything runs and I can enter the names, and age etc - however the data displays followed by the table which is blank! :(

Answer (score 2):

You would start by setting your String variables to a default value:

```
        String firstname = string.empty;
        String lastname = string.empty; 
        String age = string.empty;
```

Then, if your for loop does not execute, your variables will have an initialized value.  When accessed later in the code, the error will not happen

ADDING EDIT PER COMMENT, initialize Counter:

```
int Counter=0;
```

Comment: may as well initialize the `int` variable as well

Comment: +1 just trying to make sure the OP stays consistent lol

Comment: @DJ....thanks, we love consistency

Answer (score 1):

In C#, the error `Use of unassigned local variable` means that you are trying to use a variable that you have not given a value yet. C#, unlike some other languages, requires that you guarantee that you've assigned something (even null) to a variable before you use it - it doesn't initialize variables to default values (like VB.NET) or leave them with garbage values (like C++).

In your case, `firstname` is filled inside of a `for` loop, which means it's possible that it never gets a value if the body of the `for` loop never executes. When you try to use it inside the `do`, it's possible it's never been assigned.

To solve this, the most common way is to set it to `null` when you declare the variable, which means you've guaranteed that it will have something when you go to use it. Of course, make sure you properly handle what happens if the variable stays null all the way down the line.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler isn't smart enough to know that this loop:

```
for (Counter = 0; Counter < 1; Counter++)
```

will ALWAYS execute ONLY ONE TIME.  So it has to assume that there's a possibility that the code will not execute at all, in which case those variables would never get initialized.

If your `for` loop is REALLY intended to execute only once, just remove the `for` loop and the variables will get assigned a value before they're used.

If the counter is just for testing and you intend to execute the `for` loop multiple times, then initialize the varialbes to some dummy starting value (`null`, `""`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Try clean up your code (you don't need the for loop before the user input, it will be executed only once anyway).
Slightly change your code so you can inspect what `Console.ReadLine()` returns. 
Also , the error looks like it is happening because the variables are used somewhere but they could be unassigned (if the for look condition is not satisfied). 
Give them a value when declaring them and the error should disapper. Btw consider refactoring your code and split the main in one or more methods.

```
string firstname = string.empty; // And so on..
```

Comment: thanks for your help.. i'm getting there.. still can't get anything to appear into my table though! :(